How do I avoid circular reference in this situation?
I have three classes. Each class has it's own header.
I'd like each class to have two additional constructors to convert from the remaining two types:
// A.h
A(const B& b){}
A(const C& c){}

// B.h
B(const A& a){}
B(const C& c){}

// C.h
C(const A& a){}
C(const B& b){}

However, if I include the other two headers in each header, I will end up with a circular dependency.
What's the best way to implement this?

Use forward declarations.

Declare in header file, define (implement) in source file, together with forward declarations in the header files.

End result is the same as Resolve build errors due to circular dependency amongst classes.

(1)  Don't define the constructors in headers (e.g. not inline with the class definition)  (2)  The headers only define one class, and declare the other classes.  For example, a.h would define class A, and declare B and C  (e.g. class B; class C;  (3)  Define (implement) the constructors in source files (organised as needed).   Depending on what the constructors (and other member functions) are doing, the source file MAY need to include all three headers.

What are forward declarations in c++ and also when can i use forward declarations

I don not fully agree, forward declaration might be an option (in smaller designs) But for larger projects first define interfaces (abstract baseclasses) when you have multiple classes depending on each other. Lookup "dependency inversion"

You can use forward declarations to avoid circular references:
A.h
#ifndef AH
#define AH

class B;
class C;

class A {
public:
    A(const B& b);
    A(const C& c);
};

#endif

B.h
#ifndef BH
#define BH

class A;
class C;

class B {
public:
    B(const A& a);
    B(const C& c);
};

#endif

C.h
#ifndef CH
#define CH

class A;
class B;

class C {
public:
    C(const A& a);
    C(const B& b);
};

#endif

However, you won't be able to define your constructors in your .h files, since the compiler won't know what the forward-declared types actually look like, only that they exist.  You will have to define your constructors in your .cpp files instead, where you can #include the full class declarations, eg:
A.cpp
#include "A.h"

#include "B.h"
#include "C.h"

A::A(const B& b) {
    ...
}

A::A(const C& c) {
    ...
}

B.cpp
#include "B.h"

#include "A.h"
#include "C.h"

B::B(const A& a) {
    ...
}

B::B(const C& c) {
    ...
}

C.cpp
#include "C.h"

#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"

C::C(const A& a) {
    ...
}

C::C(const B& b) {
    ...
}


Pedantic side note: Your header file examples should include include guards :) (still upvoted though) :)

@JesperJuhl I expanded my example
